# Magento If...elseif...else. What am I missing?

Tags: attributes, blocks

May I ask what I am missing? My attributes and blocks are set. However the conditional isn't firing.

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('design_and_imprint_avail') == "Yes"): ?>

    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('design-imprint-edit')->toHtml() ?>

<?php elseif ($_product->getAttributeText('custom_design') == "Yes"): ?>

    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('custom-design-edit')->toHtml() ?>

<?php else ($_product->getAttributeText('imprint_available') == "Yes"): ?>

    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('imprint-edit')->toHtml() ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Which version of Magento you are using?

Comment: Nevermind. You shouldn't use a condition for `else` part.

Comment: Yep, `else` is the default if nothing matches the conditions in the previous `if/elsif` tests.

Answer (score 0):

`getAttributeText` should only be used for displaying values, not for conditions. It all goes south if you switch the language.
You can try this:

```
if ($_product->getData('design_and_imprint_avail')) : 
   //
elseif ($_product->getData('custom_design')) :....
```

Also, if you are doing this in the product list page, make sure the attributes involved in this if/else chain are marked with "Used in product listing" and that you rebuilt the indexes.

Comment: So then getData sets it as a "truthy" statement?  No need to add "Yes"